# How to add Opneshift config maps files to a spring boot web built in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift

Below my project structure

- I have multiple modules in one parent maven project.
- Many of above modules can also run as independent project including some of them as Openshift applications. These are spring boot applications
- Now I want to add one more module as Spring boot web application on Openshift that uses Spring web in build tomcat.
- Also I have multiple property files which are specific to environment and I load them as Configmaps on Openshift.

Now when I am trying to deploy the new web application, it is not able to use the Configmaps. It error says property file not found. I am sure this is because the Configmaps are outside of the tomcat and application.

Can I have any work around as I don't want to put those property files in the war while building but should get added when I deploy or start the pod on Openshift.

In short I want something like I can put configmaps as files into the class path spring boot web application that uses in built tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the ConfigMap-s as volumes at some path and then configure Spring Boot as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).